# openpyxl for Python dynamic lines

Tags: python, export-to-excel

I am using the openpyxl module for my Python scripts to create and edit .xlsx files directly from the script.

Now I want to save a not known amount of number on after the other. How can I increase the cell number? So if the last input was made in A4, how can I say that the next should be in A5?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.offset()` method of a cell to get a cell a particular number of rows or cells away.